# Efficient way to locate non alpha or spaces

Tags: regex, r

I want to test a vector of character strings and determine if each one contains elements that are numeric or symbols (ie I want to know if a string is more than just alpha characters and spaces).  I've solved it here but am wondering if there's a more efficient way (in R regex).

```
x <- c("ff d fdf4f", "fve dvgf", "vfev!", "rcvce rc&")
nchar(gsub("[a-zA-Z]|\\s+", "", x)) > 0
```

Comment: I'm no regex expert, but I probably would have gone for more of an `any(grepl())` sort of solution. No idea if it's more efficient.

Comment: I already gave an answer that is much better than this but a simple improvement (that doesn't gain too much) would be `gsub("[a-zA-Z]|\\s+", "", x) != ""`

Comment: Getting rid of the | in the regular expression makes the gsub solution significantly faster (22, 18 microseconds each).  But the grepl solution is a clear winner at 11 microseconds.

Comment: Ahh yes that would have even been better as `nchar` is expensive.

Comment: @Dason `nchar()` here seems to take only ~1 microsecond, of the times stated above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grepl` along with looking for characters that don't meet what you want seems to work

```
grepl("[^a-zA-Z[:space:]]", x)
```

This gives the same output as your original code

```
> x <- c("ff d fdf4f", "fve dvgf", "vfev!", "rcvce rc&")
> nchar(gsub("[a-zA-Z]|\\s+", "", x)) > 0
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
> grepl("[^a-zA-Z[:space:]]", x)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: @MatthewLundberg Makes sense, since at some level `nchar(gsub())` ought to take 2 passes, and `grepl` should only take one, I guess.

Comment: @joran I would expect that, being interpreted, R will not be able to actually prevent the creation of new objects of mode character in the gsub() solution.  If my expectations are correct, I would also expect that this has a big impact on the runtime.

Comment: Thank you Dason.  I was thinking the grep solution but my mind didn't go grepl when it should have as I wanted a logical return.  +1

Answer (score 2):

Use [`grep`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html) instead:

```
grep("[^a-zA-Z\\s]+", x, value=FALSE)
```

Comment: No need for the + in the regex (but of course it will not hurt).

Comment: @MatthewLundberg - You are right. I have no idea why I put `+` there :)

Comment: @Ωmega - I actually did the same originally.  It was mainly because I was just modifying Tyler's code and he has the + in there... (Also it took me a while to get your name properly for the @Ωmega)

Comment: @Dason - It seems that I was first who made that mistake, as my answer came 6 seconds before yours :) But as for sure we made our mistakes independently, it just prove that we are humans... ;)